# how to open a new file in php by clicking on some image click

Tags: php

I want to open a new window on image click. My code is:

```
<img src="images/input.jpg" width="100" style="border-radius:20px;
cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:window.open(<?php echo"<a
href='data.php?id=$date&id1=$d'></a>"?>,'','width=870,height=620');">
```

But it's not working; `id` and `id1` are not passed on to the next page to be opened.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try echo $date and $d, aren't those empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the direct url for `window.open` statement

```
<img src="images/input.jpg" width="100" style="border-radius:20px; cursor:pointer;"onclick="javascript:window.open(<?php echo"'data.php?id=$date&id1=$d'"?>,'','width=870,height=620');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an `<a>` tag.

You also need to encapsulate your URL in single quotes:

```
<img src="images/input.jpg" width="100" style="border-radius:20px;
cursor:pointer;"onclick="javascript:window.open('<?php echo
"data.php?id=$date&id1=$d" ?>','','width=870,height=620');">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$date   = '2013-07-01';
$id      = '1';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
  return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}

</script>
<img src="images/input.jpg" width="100" style="border-radius:20px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="popupwindow('data.php?id=<?=$date?>&id=<?=$id?>', 'Popup', 200, 200)" />
```

Comment: You just made a one-liner 14x longer.

Comment: Yes, I did. I had this function which opens the popup in the middle of the page. @DannyBeckett

Comment: ...which the OP never asked for.